# React Native Animations, Loop animation without resetting animated value after iteration

Tags: javascript, react-native, animation, react-animated

### React-Native Animated: How to loop an animation without resetting the animation value after each loop.

I was struggling to figure out a method of looping React Native Animations without resetting the animated value back to its initial value.

For example I made a simple "Sway" animation that would move my component left and right

```
  let animationX = new Animated.Value(0);

  const left = (toValue) => Animated.timing(animationX, {toValue: -toValue, duration: 1500})
  const right = (toValue) => Animated.timing(animationX, {toValue, duration: 1500})

  const startSwayAnimation = () => {
    Animated.loop(
      Animated.sequence([
        left(100),
        right(100),
      ])
    ).start()
  }
```

The problem was that my animationX variable resets back to 0 after every loop.
I couldn't find any useful resources on how to loop an animation without resetting the value, though there are two dead issues on github:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18028
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20560

I was nearly at the point of considering asking on SO, but then I tried creating a recursive function to loop the animation instead and it worked great

In case anyone else is struggling with this, or knows a better solution (perhaps some config for Animated.loop that I am unaware of) I decided to share this on SO.

Answer (score 1):

### Memory Leak Fix for above answer!!

My previous implementation resulted in a memory leak
I also figured out how to make it reusable in a custom hook!

```
const useLoopAnimation = (animationFn) => {
  // loopAnimation halts when changing state variables (using useState) for unknown reason
  // so use a let variable instead.
  let stopped = false;
  const loopAnimation = () => {
    if (stopped) return false;
    animationFn().start(() => loopAnimation());
  };

  // this runs on component dismount to stop the recursive loop.
  useEffect(() => () => {
    stopped = true;
  });
  return loopAnimation;
};
```

and then in your component you use it like so

```
  const loopAnimation = useLoopAnimation(() =>
    Animated.sequence([left(100), right(100)])
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion to call the same Animation over and over again by calling the same function in the start callback

```
  let animationX = new Animated.Value(0);
  const left = (toValue: number) =>
    Animated.timing(animationX, { toValue: -toValue, duration: 1500 });
  const right = (toValue: number) =>
    Animated.timing(animationX, { toValue, duration: 1500 });

    const loopSway = () => {
        Animated.sequence([
          left(100),
          right(100),
        ]).start(() => loopSway())
    }
```

However, I was unable to create a reusable loopAnimation function.
when I try, I get the error `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'animations[current].start')`

```
    const sway = Animated.sequence([
      left(100),
      right(100),
    ])

    const loopAnimation = (animation) => {
        animation.start(() => loopAnimation(animation))
    }

    const loopSway = loopAnimation(sway)
```

It appears there's some side effect in React Native Animated that doesn't let you assign animations as constants :(

I tried cloning the animation

```
    const loopAnimation = (animation) => {
        const animationClone = {...animation}
        animation.start(() => loopAnimation(animationClone))
    }
```

and I tried making the animation a state value.

But didn't have any success with either so would appreciate if anyone has insight on how to make this fn reusable!

Comment: It turns out this results in a memory leak, I'm working on a solution!